# SPF records pass in Gmail sends but show failure in Postmaster

Tags: domain-name-system, authentication, spf, gmail

I'm using Sparkpost as the ESP to warm up a secondary domain. We've used this Sparkpost IP for our primary domain for a few months without a problem. I've been tracking the deliverability of the secondary domain warmup and Google shows that the [SPF passing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfxJI.png)

Additionally, the email header in question shows SPF = Pass

```
Delivered-To: email@email.com
Received: by 2002:a05:6a10:bd06:b0:52e:9040:15a4 with SMTP id vu6csp442968pxb;
        Tue, 9 Jan 2024 08:41:58 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IGRcchb3ovyiw/5xuYm3ptNWuD3xyaiboPymYSIYFqSSbpv0/J5Nk8ZzMncijMzCtW8sUm5
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6a20:7d98:b0:199:fa37:8447 with SMTP id v24-20020a056a207d9800b00199fa378447mr1318364pzj.13.1704818518456;
        Tue, 09 Jan 2024 08:41:58 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1704818518; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=tXlFIFSbnuj8ZDpPdSB/D+JUdPADFCR9RqVdUTWWK2JZ7f3qfYWXLSYN7n/TiE368a
         0uuLqf8C5B62OcIgcRl0R+m3RQCLrUa8apqPC8WmVwjE+ra4Y0MyW9eZEZBaRY13tBwK
         HKx3xajWmt1CiniDQYymmj8+l/Uqz6MBcQmCMDBSlDEZy9u/3x+Fdt7qB3/R6ESXKA2f
         kRYcMHuOZ/LUw9SSFKadTXj0bAjd+94ubLyAnBBWtRCweFIVonYAu8gREkfeMfZaU9Ha
         tgzK6kO3jp/4TWYksK0JhQy5P3ZU++pyg+RwRBlRW+p6jKza+OWl2FfZjUrTvAg4GjmN
         mUJA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=from:subject:mime-version:date:message-id:to:dkim-signature;
        bh=ifMpQw6f1DKTqKjzS14PabOjSlquCfd6h2oLubLHC7k=;
        fh=h14NezYAwyCh2DizMKVSwOlIhcGGyNuwZjGVcUJxnms=;
        b=DFLRIUpGZ/Mi6C8XEDvI1YFaUPZIFq2i1UOXmDqKToQzRQ8VH1u50aj8AqnJ6toNau
         6zo6KkEu+Y7ft3nfR3VRjbnQjWpqBPpJwAEppUpSTeOEYxNVXr6idfPInUaZ9sSu+Mc7
         IjVVxTH9wXrbovp9j8SDvqpcq/7lcMkFrZD9XeZSq30/UjmnQNirH3aQ1YojmmYSnJ5e
         Tb4KfpGu4IHvx3/eaxnBUicNIqORTWOkLE7sHJDfd7cGmcMMpAr2ijVqBZwIyf7y8O2Y
         JQzqO0RTp3d9A1mHixDeLuGwBkRkod1RNe8DAFNonfLk4eLdQIy12zEEScbhzvECdb+C
         6PYw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@masterworks-offerings.com header.s=scph1223 header.b=l94eYBOq;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of msprvs1=19738jlkdimxa=bounces-345806@b.masterworks.com designates 156.70.150.33 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="msprvs1=19738JlKdimXA=bounces-345806@b.masterworks.com";
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=masterworks-offerings.com
Return-Path: <msprvs1=19738JlKdimXA=bounces-345806@b.masterworks.com>
Received: from mta-70-150-33.sparkpostmail.com (mta-70-150-33.sparkpostmail.com. [156.70.150.33])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id u22-20020a63f656000000b005cddb4051ffsi1667474pgj.25.2024.01.09.08.41.58
        for <etu@masterworks.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 09 Jan 2024 08:41:58 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of msprvs1=19738jlkdimxa=bounces-345806@b.masterworks.com designates 156.70.150.33 as permitted sender) client-ip=156.70.150.33;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@masterworks-offerings.com header.s=scph1223 header.b=l94eYBOq;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of msprvs1=19738jlkdimxa=bounces-345806@b.masterworks.com designates 156.70.150.33 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="msprvs1=19738JlKdimXA=bounces-345806@b.masterworks.com";
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=masterworks-offerings.com
X-MSFBL: mxFOaiVyP8wgxeRuZCQPIuoOwf1rPY4boEqCJ7zuYCw=|eyJjdXN0b21lcl9pZCI 6IjM0NTgwNiIsInN1YmFjY291bnRfaWQiOiIwIiwidGVuYW50X2lkIjoic3BjIiw iciI6ImV0dUBtYXN0ZXJ3b3Jrcy5jb20iLCJtZXNzYWdlX2lkIjoiNjU5ODU1Nzc 5ZDY1YzliZjFjOWIifQ==
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=masterworks-offerings.com; s=scph1223; t=1704818517; i=@masterworks-offerings.com; bh=ifMpQw6f1DKTqKjzS14PabOjSlquCfd6h2oLubLHC7k=; h=To:Message-ID:Date:Content-Type:Subject:From:From:To:Cc:Subject; b=l94eYBOqtXnkPb8t9tnY9E0qtIrRv1KikdCfaMQLYtEWBqaP4kaD4HkSoLwmEm2kI
     eVyU5cH7MFbaOgJt88W7gSxVDIQDDxPOFujLLXHuRXVCG2iEPRiVfNiIAwbVu/YxSv
     4xUvgYGZH7/C6Feu9WNckRLtCRNBAiYLwRNlRAVI=
To: email@email.com
Message-ID: <xxxxx>
Date: Tue, 09 Jan 2024 16:41:57 +0000
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_----TSvzDTxPUpPzesYOhQax7g===_10/B9-32230-5577D956"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Test
From: email <email@masterworks-offerings.com>

--_----TSvzDTxPUpPzesYOhQax7g===_10/B9-32230-5577D956
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
```

However, Postmaster is reporting a 0% SPF success rate which may be degrading our secondary domain reputation. Has anyone else experienced this issue and identified a potential solution? Thank you for your time

Comment: What is "Postmaster" in this context?

Comment: @KeithLangmead I'm referring to Google's tool Postmaster, which shows stats about domains like IP reputation, spam rate, etc. This data is limited to Google, as we are seeing normal deliverability with other providers like Yahoo and AOL

Comment: I don't know anything about Sparkpost or Postmaster, so those questions should be directed at their support staff. If you are having issues with SPF failures, you likely need to post an SPF failure. One test would be to create a DMARC record to include RUA and RUF, which will also report results of SPF tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postmaster likely shows the `DMARC` related `SPF` result as failing, due to the `SPF` alignment for your emails. Because `SPF` is checked on the `Return-Path` domain, which is `b.masterworks.com`, while the `FROM` domain is `masterworks-offerings.com`.

`DMARC` requires alignment between the `SPF` domain and the `FROM` domain, in order to Pass `DMARC` checks (on `SPF`). Additionally, even if you change the organizational domain to match the FROM domain, because the `Return-Path` is sending from a subdomain, `DMARC` authentication will fail on `SPF` alignment due to the `SPF` alignment tag in the `DMARC` policy record is set to strict (`aspf=s`). This requires the both domains to exactly match.

To fix this alignment issue: Change the organizational domain in the `Return-Path` header and remove the `aspf` tag, so it takes the default value of `r` (relaxed).

Comment: This worked, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Good to hear that :)